# Return string[] from string in c # class property

Tags: c#

Data incoming from a SQL Server has a field with a pipe delimited string IE:

> 20190819|20190830|20190915

I would like my Class property to return a `string[]`. I can manually do it with split, but I want my class property to perform the calculation and conversion.

Comment: Create a readonly property. The `get` of the property will call `string.Split`.

Comment: @mjwills While that is correct, it's bad practice to have properties that have side effects - I'm not a fan.

Comment: @DavidG We'll have to agree to disagree. I think that generally when people talk about side effects in a property this is not necessarily the kind of scenario they are talking about.

Answer (score 0):

```
   /* Use MyObject like below:

        var b = new MyObject();
        b.datesString = "20190819|20190830|20190915"; //set datesList to list of strings
        var ss = new List<string> { "a", "b" };
        b.datesList = ss; //set datesString to 'a|b'

    */

    public class MyObject {
        public string datesString {get;set;}
        public IEnumerable<string> datesList
        {
            get
            {
                if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(datesString))
                {
                    return null;// or new empty list
                }
                return datesString.Split('|');
            }
            set
            {
                if(value != null)
                {
                    datesString = "";
                    foreach(var s in value)
                    {
                        datesString += s + "|";
                    }
                    datesString = datesString.Substring(0, datesString.Length - 1);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```